# What is the best way of converting SOAP to REST

Tags: json, rest, soap

I have few SOAP services exists in my code which produces XML as my response type. I would like to conver this SOAP to RESTful webservice by producing `"Application/JSON"`. So please suggest is there any tool to convert SOAP to REST or any other way of re-using SOAP as Restful service.

Comment: Good luck here. Especially without telling us what's your programming language nor the libraries used...

Comment: I have used Java as my programming language. I have implemented Service EndPoint with few SOAP services and RESTful services. With the help of gensor jar i could produce response in JSON format and now i would like to convert all the SOAP to RESTful service.